Session.sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query' : Snowflake
I have an error with this code:
# The Snowpark package is required for Python Worksheets. 
# You can add more packages by selecting them using the Packages control and then importing them.

import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark


def execute_query(session: snowpark, query):
    df = session.sql(query)
    return df

def test_execute_query(session: snowpark.Session):
    query = "SHOW TABLES IN DEV.TRANSIT"
    return execute_query(session, query)

session_param = snowpark.Session
test_execute_query(session_param)

When try i have this :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 16, in <module>
  Worksheet, line 13, in test_execute_query
  Worksheet, line 8, in execute_query
TypeError: Session.sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'

Normaly i want to use current session with parameter to execute any query

session_param = snowpark.Session Perhaps you forgot the parentheses here?  Is that supposed to be session_param = snowpark.Session() instead?

do not work need need to add connection paramters but i want to use a current session Traceback (most recent call last):   Worksheet, line 15, in <module> TypeError: Session.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'conn'

am confused ... .where is this 'current session' , at what point have you connected to an instance to formally established a session ?

you do not have an active session so there is no session for you to use.   Session:   does not create a session.    You need to create a session and store a reference to it and pass it to your methods if you want to use an existing one.   Otherwise you need to create a new session and use that reference.   Any AI tool and search,  Show me how to connect to snowflake using snowpark.
